# javascript issue in safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

Hello I'm calling a function from my .js plugin in HTML onclick method, all works fine in other browsers but not only in Safari. Please suggest me some alternative so the function works fine in all browsers.

Thanks..

and my code is:

```
<table border="1"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1" value="daily" onclick="xyz1()"/></td>
                <td><font class="fnt-12">Daily</font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1" value="weekly" onclick="xyz1()" /></td>
                <td><font class="fnt-12">Weekly</font></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

and the function in the .js plugin is:

```
function xyz1()
{
    var currentSelection=$('#getCurrentSelection').html();
    var radio = $('input:radio[name=radio1]:checked').val();

    if(radio=="daily")
    {
        alert("daily.....");
        $("div.weeklyContent1").hide();

        $('div.dailyContent').show();

            // $(".weeklyContent").html("dfgdf");
           //  $(".weeklyContent").html($(".dailyContent").html());

    }
    if(radio=="weekly")
    {   alert("weekly.....");
        $('div.dailyContent').hide();
        $("div.weeklyContent1").show();

    }
}
```

Comment: you could also create a fiddle as jsfiddle.net and put the link here, it will let us see your code.

Comment: Start by having valid HTML.. give unique ID to the radio buttons e.g. change the second ID to `id="radio2"`.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - its not working

Comment: OK, but that was first crucial step. Now please add the following after the first two lines of your function: `alert(radio);` - what do you see in the alert message after clicking a radio button?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - no any alert displayed in Safari, in other browsers it displays daily for daily option and weekly for weekly option.

Comment: Weird.. try such onclick then: `onclick="javascript:xyz1();"` - any luck?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - I'm sorry, also not working..

Comment: can someone tell me any error detecting tool for Safari browser..?

Comment: Safari has its 'Web inspector' built in. Just go to the 'Develop' menu (or preferences >advanced>show develop toolbar then go to develop). Then when thats open just go to the Console tab. Which version of safari do you have? Because that code works in my safari? http://jsfiddle.net/7eRfm/1/

Also just a note, it's 70% faster to use the attribute selector, `input[type=radio]` instead of `input:radio` (the pseudo selector). See http://jsperf.com/pseudo-selector-vs-attribute-selector. You can chain attribute selectors as well e.g. `input[type=radio][name=radio1]` for greater performance.

Comment: Maybe JS is simply turned off in the Safari browser.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - please tell me where to check for these settings in Safari browser..?

Comment: See [here](http://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?answer=12654) under `Apple Safari (1.0)` section.

Answer (score 1):

Change `onclick="xyz1()"` to `onchange="xyz1()"`.

ids are singular, you can not have id="radio1" in two places!

But you are using jQuery, so why do you have inline JavaScript in the first place. Add the handlers

```
$(
    function(){
        $('input:radio[name=radio1]').change( xyz1 );
    }
);
```